# Immutablejs - map not making nested objects immutable

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I am setting up a map like so:

```
import { Map } from 'immutable';

const initialState = {
   a: "test",
   b: {
    inside: "inside value"
   }
} 

const otherState = {
   c: "other value"
}

 const myState = new Map({ app: new Map(initialState).merge(otherState) });
```

This seemed to be working, however when I try to change values inside the nested object it does not seem to be working for me (I'm getting "invalid keypath"). So trying:

```
myState.setIn(['app', 'b', 'inside'], 'newValue');
```

is giving me an "invalid keypath" error. It's looking like When I log it out that the nested object is not being turned immutable. Unsure what I am doing incorrectly.

Edit - here is a codepen to show the problem - https://codepen.io/ajmajma/pen/rRQoZp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the correct path should be `['app', 'b', 'inside']` given that `app` is the only property of the `myState` object.

You also need to `Immutable.fromJS()` your `initialState` and `otherState` objects, otherwise nested keys are treated as JS objects, not immutablejs maps.

```
const myState = new Map({ app: new Map(Immutable.fromJS(initialState)).merge(Immutable.fromJS(otherState)) });
```

Comment: Typo by me - sorry! I added a codepen to demonstrate the issue.